# How do you manually create GridView groups and fill them with items?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have just created a `GroupedItemsPage` and I would like to add some groups, then fill them with items. I do not want to use a `databinding` because the items do not need to be modified by code. I would like the items to be from a specific template and to be able to set the group titles.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a ScrollViewer with Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" and put a StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal" in it, then use Grids, WrapGrids and/or VariableSizedWrapGrids to display the content. If not using ItemsSource bindings - you might be better off building it from scratch.